# Alternative to getProgramAccounts?

Tags: python, api, helius

It seems Helius depreciated getGetProgramAccounts:
https://www.helius.dev/blog/solana-account-webhooks

I'd like to be able to query, for an SPL, the token addresses of all holders. Is there a manually way I can do this or some workaround if I use the helius API?
I'm a bit new to solana, the only way I can think of is querying all transactions and then groupby account and netting all transactions...

Also trying to do this in python

Comment: Looks like a duplicate. Does this help you? https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/8653/get-holder-count

Comment: `getProgramAccounts` is a very expensive api for the node providers, you can try dedicated node providers or run one yourself.

Comment: @Bharath, this is outdated since helius doesn't support getprogramaccounts anymore.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Holder count](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/8653/get-holder-count)